# scan string and put them in vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I want to use vectors of c++.I want to know how do I scan (or cin) strings into a vector. The size of vectors is given by the user.

Comment: Hi Shane, this question is a little too broad. You will need to first learn C++ until you can make your own attempt at an implementation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I edited the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what you are asking, but it's might be as simple as this

```
vector<string> vec;
while (something)
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    vec.push_back(str);
}
```

Not sure from your question when you want to stop reading strings, i.e. what you want instead of `something` in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Vector you can understand it as "dynamic array".
You don't have to define the size.

Just simple like this:

```
vector<string> myVector;
cin >> str; // read a string value or any other data type: int, double, float.
myVector.push_back(str); // the string will be added to the end of "array"..
```